# How to do separate login for frontend and backend in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using an application in which customer can also login from frontend. Its working, but problem is in this case is customer can also see backend functionality. Vice-versa, when i login in backend, I automatically signin in fronend also. It cause problem for me.

Anyone please suggest me for implementing separate login for admin and customer in a website.

Or is there other way to do this? please suggest.

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: @jurgemaister I am using following code for this

`if($this->Auth->user())
  {
   $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'Dashboards', 'action'=>'index'));
  }`

Comment: Do some research on roles. There is no code duplication needed. Just check for a role and act accordingly.

Comment: use prefix routing , different themes(frontend backend) for each user type http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a separate login, you just need to use roles (or some variation of them).

The basic idea is, when someone logs in, you can check their 'role', and then act accordingly.

So, if someone logs in, and they're a "user", send them to the user profile page.  If they're an "admin", send them to the admin dashboard.

Then, use some form of a check to verify access rights before a user gets into an action.

**One example would be to set up a `isAuthorized()` method in your AppController.  [See more details here, in the CakePHP book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authorization-who-s-allowed-to-access-what).**

This will allow you to compare the controller/action they're trying to access, their role, and the URL prefix (if you're using /admin/... as example) and determine if they should be granted access.

There are MANY ways to handle this situation, but the basic idea is there.  Find out who they are, and what role they are, and build your logic to determine 1) where they should go, and 2) where they're allowed to go.

Comment: Thanks @Dave, I did exactly by your point, but at same time I can't login in frontend adn backend, because it create same 1 session for that. I just want that admin can login in backend and also at same time admin can login in frontend.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding below code in cakephp appcontroller beforeFilter function.

if($this->params['prefix'] == 'admin'){

```
        $this->layout = 'admin';
        AuthComponent::$sessionKey = 'Auth.Admin';
        $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email'),
                'scope' => array ('User.role_id' => '1', 'User.status' => 1),
            )
        );
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users','action' => 'login','admin' => true);
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'users','action' => 'dashboard','admin' => true);
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users','action' => 'login','admin' => true);

    }else{
        AuthComponent::$sessionKey = 'Auth.User';
        $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email'),
                'scope' => array ('User.role_id >' => '2','User.status' => 1),
            )
        );

        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users','action' => 'login');
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'users','action' => 'dashboard');
        if($this->Session->read('Auth.User.role_id') == CORPORATE){
            $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users','action' => 'corporate_login');
        }else{
            $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users','action' => 'login');
        }

    }
```

if you have don't have roles than you can remove it from scope..